# How to make matplotlib plots "finer" without having to set all individual settings?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, dpi

I have a plot that I'm saving with `plt.savefig`. However, I don't like that everything looks so bulky: the line width, the font size etc.

I know that I can do `plt.rcParams.update({"font.size": 8})` and so on for all the settings that I don't like - but

1. I might miss something and I will have to keep adjusting those settings
2. There has to be a better way?

I was thinking maybe there is a way to change all of those at once via one specific setting or method? Something like `plt.thickness(-1)` when 0 is the default. And if I want to make everything super thick (for a poster or something), I could `plt.thickness(3)`. The `dpi` argument of `plt.savefig` changes only the DPI of the whole image.

Comment: Change the figure size.

Answer (score 1):

Seaborn *set_context* has four customizable built-in functions for efficiently changing display types: paper, notebook, talk, and poster. By using this, you can change things like line width and font size in one go without altering your other style choices.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_context.html

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.read_csv("ORR.txt", sep='\t')
c = df['WE(1).Current (A)']*1000
p = df['WE(1).Potential (V)']

sns.set_context('notebook')

_ = plt.plot(p,c)

_ = plt.title('Oxygen Reduction Polarization Curve')
_ = plt.ylabel('Current (mA)')
_ = plt.xlabel('Potential (V)')

plt.savefig("notebook.pdf")
```

[image]

```
sns.set_context('talk', font_scale=0.8)

_ = plt.plot(p,c)

_ = plt.title('Oxygen Reduction Polarization Curve')
_ = plt.ylabel('Current (mA)')
_ = plt.xlabel('Potential (V)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig("talk.pdf")
```

[image]